# Discrete graph / bar graph with wxMathPlot

Tags: c++, graph, wxwidgets

I have a wxWidgets programm with gcc compiler and wxSmith which shows how many licenses are used at what time. Therefore I managed to integrade a wxMathPlot graph but unfortunately it connects all points as you can see below.
[image]

As you can imagine, that is not ideal for such a graph as I have discrete update times and between them the licenses are the same. So I would not have growing lines but something like a bar graph. Is there a way to make a discrete graph using wxMathPlot? I would not like to use another graph plugin.

Thank you for your help and sorry if the mathematical terms are not correct.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround for this problem. It is still a graph like the one above, but when you add entries only a small fracture before the number of licenses changes, with the same number of licenses as the entry before, the gradients are either 0 or near infinity.
[image]